# Effect of quotes when setting PS1

Tags: command-line, bash, special-characters, ps1

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have a question for setting PS1 and using single quotation marks. I have been practicing to change a prompt.  So, I have followed an example in the book, then I'm faced a curiosity.

The example is below:

```
user1@myubuntu:~$ PS1='$PWD '
/home/user1
```

I learned that single quotation marks make special characters (like `$`, ``` `` ```, `\`, etc.) to general characters.

So, I think the prompt above the statement must be like below:

```
user1@myubuntu:~$ PS1='$PWD '
$PWD
```

Why does the special character (`$`) still work in the single quotation marks?

Comment: type `echo $PS1`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash (and other shells) don't print `PS1` as-is. They interpret it, and the display the output. Bash, for example, expands various special codes like `\u`, `\w`, etc., and then ([from the Bash manual, *Controlling the Prompt*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)):

> After the string is decoded, it is expanded via parameter expansion,
>   command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal, subject
>   to the value of the `promptvars` shell option (see [Bash Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)).

[Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (i.e., variable expansion) means that a string like `$PWD` in `PS1` is expanded. If you want to show a plain `$PWD` in the prompt, do either of:

```
PS1='\$PWD '
# or
shopt -u promptvars
PS1='$PWD '
```